# The ancient concept of Finite Space

Tags: infinity

How do you think it possible for the ancients to be satisfied with the concept of FINITE SPACE, with "fixed stars" at its limits? To our minds, the idea of infinite extension comes so naturally, without the slightest effort, even for the mathematically unsophisticated. So what is really hiding here?

Comment: Never read [Alexandre Koyré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandre_Koyr%C3%A9)'s [From the Closed World to the Infinite Universe](https://books.google.it/books?id=Mp2Gg_F5sdIC&printsec=frontcover) (1957) ? The "conceptual transformation" was not natural nor easy at all.

Comment: You must take into account that ancient do not have "modern" concept of *space*; for them the relevant concept was that of "finite cosmos".

Comment: What infinite extension?  If you believe in the Big Bang then the universe is finite.

Comment: @MikhailKatz ... A "big bang" singularity is consistent with unbounded space.

Comment: True but I believe most of models pursued in physics nowadays use finite space.

Comment: Off-topic here but try https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150666/infinite-universe-and-big-bang ... from questions there is seems this misconception is common among amateurs

Comment: Here is a quote from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold): "Calabi–Yau manifolds are complex manifolds that are generalizations of K3 surfaces in any number of complex dimensions (i.e. any even number of real dimensions). They were originally defined as compact Kähler manifolds with a vanishing first Chern class and a Ricci-flat metric, though many other similar but inequivalent definitions are sometimes used." Calabi-Yau manifolds are commonly used as such models. @GeraldEdgar

Answer (score 2):

Who believed in a closed world? The fathers of science, the Old Greek, did not.

Anaxagoras 499-428 BC knew: Of the great there is no greatest but there is always a greater.

Anaximander of Milet 611-547 BC already said: The infinite (apeiron) is not exhaustible. Wherever the warrior stays, he can stretch out his spear farther.

Comment: I am not much of an expert in astrophysics  but it seems to me that modern science tells us quite the opposite: space is finite.  As far as the spear objection is concerned, the rebuttal is that you may eventually stab yourself in the back.

Comment: The geometry described in Euclid's *Elements* is certainly unbounded.  The parallel postulate shows that.  And it is said that geometry was studied by the ancients as a model for the actual world, not (as today) some abstraction.

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to the idea of the [firmament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmament) as " the structure above the atmosphere, conceived as a vast solid dome."  *(Upvoted regardless for your two very excellent references;)*